# Adding SQLite entry not in onCreate method

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, oncreate

The fact is that I am using SQLite to create a database which stores the puntuation of a game.
I need a number, the puntuation, which will update when it must to.
I created a class extending SQLiteOpenHelper, named MonedasSQLite.

But the database is empty yet. To introduce information, in the onCreate method of the Game.java class, I write this:

```
private MonedasSQLite base_monedas = new MonedasSQLite(this, "DBMonedas", null, 1);
base_monedas.insertarReg(0,0);
base_monedas.cerrar();
```

Where insertarReg is:

```
public void insertarReg(Integer cod, Integer mon) {
    ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
    valores.put("codigo", cod);
    valores.put("money", mon);
    this.getWritableDatabase().insert("monedas", null, valores);
}
```

And cerrar() is just for closing:

```
public void cerrar() {
    this.close();
}
```

Doing so, everytime the user goes into the layout with the Game.java assigned, a new row of values (0,0) is being created. This way, when the user has entered 5 times there, the content of the database is (imagine the current puntuation is 100):

(0,100)
(0,100)
(0,100)
(0,100)
(0,0) --> As I am updating the (1st column=0 value) when the user does something OK, all the rows are updated. The last one not yet, because it has just been created.

**What I am looking for is how can I create an entry of (0,0) out of the onCreate(), so that my database only has a row.**

Hope somebody could help me! Hope too that I was clear in my explanation, if not please ask and I will write more code or information needed.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise you to take a look at this tutorial 
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

and

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Its very simple and will help you create a good solid and well built SQL TABLE.

hope it helps